# Figure drawn without function call?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am getting a problem in java program for moving a circle. The program has 2 basic buttons:

START: used for moving the circle

STOP: used for exiting the program

My problem is that the circle appears before I press the start button. However I make the call  to move only when START Button is pressed which makes the call to repaint and then the circle should appear. But it appears by default. I have no problem in moving the circle. Here is my source code:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 class Moving extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {
   JButton start,stop;Move mypanel;

   Moving()
   {
    setTitle("Moving circle");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(800,600);
    start=new JButton("START");
    stop=new JButton("STOP");
    start.addActionListener(this);stop.addActionListener(this);
    JPanel p=new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p.add(start);p.add(stop);
    getContentPane().add(p,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    mypanel=new Move();
    getContentPane().add(mypanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

   }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
    String s=e.getActionCommand();
    if(s.equals("STOP"))
            System.exit(0);
    else if(s.equals("START")) 
            mypanel.move();     
   }
   public static void main(String []args)
   {
    Moving obj=new Moving();
    obj.setVisible(true);
   }
 }

 class Move extends JPanel
 { static int x=80, cv=0;
  public void move()
  {     
    repaint();
  }
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    setBackground(Color.green);

    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    if(x<500&&cv==0)
        {g.fillOval(x, 80, 100, 100);this.inc();}
    else if((x>=500||cv==1)&&x>=80)
    {
     cv=1;g.fillOval(x, 80, 100, 100);this.dec();
    }
    else cv=0;      
  }
  public void inc()
  {
    x+=10;
  }
  public void dec()
  {
    x-=10;
  }
 }
```

Comment: `paintComponent()` is called when the object is shown. If you want to call it only from `move()`, then you need to adjust your code. BTW naming the method `move()` is a bit confusing (looks like a constructor at first sight).

Comment: I would consider to do call the `repaint` method outside of the `Move` class. Also, if you take the calls to the `inc` and `dec` methods out of the `paintComponent` method (to - for example - the `move` method), to separate paint code  from move code.

Comment: You're calling `mypanel=new Move();` in constructor of `Moving` class. So when an object of `Moving` is initialized it will show the `jpanel` of `Move` class, that's why you are viewing that panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `setVisible` would be true. So, if you don't won't to show panel on load then make it `false` on constructor.

And then make it visible when you hit Start.

See below:

```
class Move extends JPanel {
    static int x = 80, cv = 0;

    Move(){
        setVisible(false); <-- Make it false here
    }

    public void move() {
        this.setVisible(true);     <----- make it visible here when you click start
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        setBackground(Color.green);
         ..... REMAINING CODE
    }
}
```

Comment: I do want to show the panel when my program begins, what i do not understand is how come the action is getting performed, even when the button is not pressed , please explain.

Comment: You're calling `mypanel=new Move();` in constructor of `Moving` class. So when an object of `Moving` is initialized it will show the `jpanel` of `Move` class and by default it's visibility is `true`, so it will be shawn to you

Comment: But why the line g.fillOval(x,80,100,100) is getting executed without any pressing of button? The Cirle is getting drawn without any button being pressed, this means the line is getting executed without any button being pressed. I do not get it.

Comment: `setVisible()` is by default true. And when it's called it will call `repaint()` internally, and that's why `g.fillOval(x,80,100,100)` is getting executed.

Comment: When you set `setVisible(false)` then it won't execute `repaint()` and that line won't be shown then. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that if you do not want to show your circle before the pressing of the start button you have to remove drawing of the circle from the `paintComponent` method.

You can achieve the above by declaring a new method in your `Move` class say `drawCircle` like this:

```
public void drawCircle(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    if(x<500&&cv==0)
        {g.fillOval(x, 80, 100, 100);this.inc();}
    else if((x>=500||cv==1)&&x>=80)
    {
     cv=1;g.fillOval(x, 80, 100, 100);this.dec();
    }
    else cv=0;      
}
```

now in your `Move` class introduce a new `boolean` variable say `circleShowing` and intialise to `false`. This is declared so that the `paintComponent` method of the `Move` class can decide whether the circle should be drawn or not. You can do it like this:

```
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    setBackground(Color.green);
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(circleShowing){
       drawCircle(g);
    }
  }
```

Now finally in the `actionPerformed` method of your `Moving` class you in the `else if` block you could write the following:

```
mypanel.circleShowing = true;
mypanel.move();
```

I hope if you make these changes this will work as you wish.

Comment: 1-, Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions when posting example code.

Comment: @camickr Ok I have corrected the same and do you find anything else wrong with my answer?

Comment: Downvote removed. The reset seems reasonable. That is use a property of the class to control what is painted is a good design.